# javascript doesn't work in all elements of foreach MVC

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, foreach

i build a code for comments and replies of them.. i use a `@foreach`to show all elements in `ViewBag` which have a list of comments..
every thing works fine in post and get ..
but my problem it's when i try to make "submit"button of replies disable to prevent anyone from pressing it without typing..
so i use `javascript` but the code didn't work fine ..
first it work only with the last element of `@foreach` .. after i use the name as "class" instead of "id" it work for all elements
but the problem is .. if i typing in first reply input text for example .. the button didn't enable .. but if i typing at last reply input text .. all buttons enable ..
I want the code work for each reply .. only when some one typing in that input text ..

JavaScript

```js
<script>            
      var $inputreply = $('.replies');
      var $buttonreply = $('.replysubmit');

      setInterval(function () {
            if ($inputreply.val().length > 0) {
                $buttonreply.prop('disabled', false);
                } 
           else {
                $buttonreply.prop('disabled', true);
                }
                }, 100);                      
</script>
```

View which have loop `@foreach`of comments and replies for each comment

```html
<section class="comment-list">
                @foreach (var item in ViewBag.CommentsList)
                {                     
                    <article class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-10 col-sm-10">
                            <div class="panel panel-default arrow left">
                                <div class="panel-body">
                                    <header class="text-left" style="direction:rtl;">
                                        <time class="comment-date" datetime="16-12-2014 01:05"><i class="fa fa-clock-o"></i> @item.CommentDateTime</time>
                                    </header>
                                    <div class="comment-post">
                                        <p>@item.Comment</p>

                                    </div>
                                    <p class="text-right"><a class="btn btn-default btn-sm replybtn"><i class="fa fa-reply"></i> reply</a></p>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <!--ReplyBox-->
                            @if (Request.IsAuthenticated)
                            {
                                using (Html.BeginForm("Reply", "Home", new { @id = @item.PostID, @commentId = @item.ID }, FormMethod.Post))
                                {
                                    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()                                                                                 
                                    <div class="input-group" style="direction:ltr;">
                                        <input type="text" class="replies form-control" placeholder="" name="replies" />
                                        <span class="input-group-btn">
                                            <button class="replysubmit btn btn-primary" type="submit">Reply</button>
                                        </span>
                                    </div>
                                }
                                
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                <div class="form-horizontal">
                                    <div class="alert alert-danger replybox" style="display:none;">
                                        <span>please login to reply</span>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            }
                            @foreach (var subitem in ViewBag.Relies)
                            {
                                if (@subitem.CommentID == @item.ID)
                                {
                                    <article class="row">
                                        <div class="col-md-9 col-sm-9">
                                            <div class="panel panel-default arrow left">
                                                <div class="panel-heading left">Reply</div>
                                                <div class="panel-body">
                                                    <header class="text-left">
                                                        <time class="comment-date" datetime="16-12-2014 01:05"><i class="fa fa-clock-o"></i> @subitem.ReplyDate</time>
                                                    </header>
                                                    <div class="comment-post">
                                                        <p>@subitem.CommentReply</p>
                                                    </div>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-2 col-md-offset-1 col-sm-offset-0 hidden-xs">
                                            <figure class="thumbnail">
                                                <img class="img-responsive" src="http://www.keita-gaming.com/assets/profile/default-avatar-c5d8ec086224cb6fc4e395f4ba3018c2.jpg" />
                                                <figcaption class="text-center">@subitem.UserName</figcaption>
                                            </figure>
                                        </div>
                                    </article>
                                }

                            }

                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-2 hidden-xs">
                            <figure class="thumbnail">
                                <img class="img-responsive" src="http://www.keita-gaming.com/assets/profile/default-avatar-c5d8ec086224cb6fc4e395f4ba3018c2.jpg" />
                                <figcaption class="text-center">@item.userName</figcaption>
                            </figure>
                        </div>
                    </article>
                    <br />


                }
            </section>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The selector `$('.replysubmit')` returns all the items with that css class, hence updating the disabled property of all those elements, not just the one closest to the input element.

You should use a relative selector to get the submit button inside the form where the reply input element is.

jQuery `closest()` and `find()` methods will be  handy

This should work

```
$(function () {

    $('.replysubmit').prop('disabled', true); // Disable all buttons when page loads

    // On the keyup event, disable or enable the buttons based on input 
    $(".replies").keyup(function() {

        if ($(this).val().length > 0) {
            $(this).closest("form").find(".replysubmit").prop('disabled', false);
        } else {
            $(this).closest("form").find(".replysubmit").prop('disabled', true);
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Works very efficiently .. Thanks a lot :))